# python no output when using pool.map_async

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, pool, python-itertools

I am experiencing very strange issues while working with the data inside my function that gets called by pool.map.  For example, the following code works as expected...

```
import csv
import multiprocessing
import itertools
from collections import deque

cur_best = 0
d_sol = deque(maxlen=9)
d_names = deque(maxlen=9)

**import CSV Data1**

def calculate(vals):
    #global cur_best
    sol = sum(int(x[2]) for x in vals)
    names = [x[0] for x in vals]
    print(", ".join(names) + " = " + str(sol))

def process():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    prod = itertools.product(([x[2], x[4], x[10]] for x in Data1))
    result = pool.map_async(calculate, prod)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result

process()
```

Now when I add a simple if-statement to calculate(), I get no output.

```
   def calculate(vals):
        #global cur_best
        sol = sum(int(x[2]) for x in vals)
        if sol > cur_best:
             cur_best = sol
             names = [x[0] for x in vals]
             print(", ".join(names) + " = " + str(cur_best))
             #would like to append cur_best and names to a deque
```

I have tried adjusting where I declare 'cur_best' to no avail.

I am trying to keep track of the 'current best' solution as I am running through the calculations.  In my linear code, this logic resides in a nested for-loop and I append each new 'cur_best' to a deque.

Do my new issues relate to the way pool.map or pool.map_async work?  Can I no longer treat my calculate() function as a linear loop?

There are several other conditional statements I need to address.  Should I be handling this in a different part of the code?  And if so, how exactly?

Comment: is `global` commented out in your actual code?

Comment: Using `multiprocessing` will create several processes (here 4) with each their own value of the global `cur_best`, so your code structure won't work.

Comment: @JasonS yes global is commented out

Comment: @ArminRigo then why doesnt each process just print its own results?  I dont understand why I am getting zero output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are likely two things going on here. First, the reason you're not seeing anything printed from the worker function is probably because it's throwing an exception. Because you're using `map_async`, you won't actually see the exception until you call `result.get()`. However, since you're callnig `close`/`join` on the pool right after using `map_async`, you should probably just use `map` instead, which will block until all the work is complete (or an exception is thrown). I'm not sure *why* the exception is happening (nothing jumps out from the code you provided), but my guess would be you're pulling the wrong index from your list somewhere.

Second, as Armin Rigo pointed out, `cur_best` is not shared between all processes, so your logic won't work the way you're intending. I think the easiest option is to use a [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) to create an integer in shared memory, which will be accessible to all processes.

To append the results you're getting to a `deque`, you would need to create shared deques, using a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). A `Manager` spawns a server process that can manage shared access to an object (like a `deque`). Each process in you pool (as well as the parent process) gets access to a [`Proxy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) object, which can communicate with the Manager's process to read/write to the shared object.

Here's an example showing everything discussed above:

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing
from collections import deque
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, MakeProxyType

class DequeManager(BaseManager):
   pass

BaseDequeProxy = MakeProxyType('BaseDequeProxy', (
    '__add__', '__contains__', '__delitem__', '__getitem__', '__len__',
    '__mul__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setitem__',
    'append', 'count', 'extend', 'extendleft', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 
    'remove', 'reverse', 'sort', 'appendleft', 'popleft', 'rotate', 
    '__imul__'
    ))
class DequeProxy(BaseDequeProxy):
    def __iadd__(self, value):
        self._callmethod('extend', (value,))
        return self
    def __imul__(self, value):
        self._callmethod('__imul__', (value,))
        return self

DequeManager.register('deque', deque, DequeProxy)


cur_best = d_sol = d_names = None

def init_globals(best, sol, names):
    """ This will be called in each worker process. 

    A global variable (cur_best) will be created in each worker.
    Because it is a multiprocessing.Value, it will be shared
    between each worker, too.

    """
    global cur_best, d_sol, d_names
    cur_best = best
    d_sol = sol
    d_names = names

def calculate(vals):
    global cur_best
    sol = sum(int(x[2]) for x in vals)
    if sol > cur_best.value:
        cur_best.value = sol
        names = [x[0] for x in vals]
        print(", ".join(names) + " = " + str(cur_best.value))
        d_sol.append(cur_best.value)
        d_names.append(names)
    return sol

def process():
    global d_sol, d_names
    cur_best = multiprocessing.Value("I", 0)  # unsigned int

    m = DequeManager()
    m.start()
    d_sol = m.deque(maxlen=9)
    d_names = m.deque(maxlen=9)  

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4, initializer=init_globals, 
                                initargs=(cur_best, d_sol, d_names))
    prod = itertools.product([x[2], x[4], x[10]] for x in Data1)
    result = pool.map(calculate, prod)  # map instead of map_async
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result  # Result will be a list containing the value of `sol` returned from each worker call

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    print(process())
```

Comment: ty for such a detailed explanation.  a few issues: the deques are only coming back with one value (even though set to maxlen=9).  most recent changes: in my calculate() i need to use float so it is now sol = sum(float(x[2]) for x in vals) likewise in process() I changed from unsigned int to float via cur_best = multiprocessing.Value("f", 0)

Comment: is each worker process clearing the deques and then appending the most recent result?  looking at the structure of init_globals and how cur_best = d_sol = d_names = None is defined... this is my best guess

Comment: doing some testing, im getting an error saying AutoProxy[deque] object does not support indexing.  after some research it looks like I need to define _iter_ from BaseProxy in order for the class to be iterable

Comment: @nodoze Just use `d_sol.value` to get at the actual deque.

Comment: im sorry, where in the code would I use this?  printing d_sol.value doesnt work.  hitting a learning curve ...

Comment: @nodoze Oh, I at least partially know what the issue is now. The default `Proxy` object used by `BaseManager` won't work properly with a container (like `deque`). What methods on `deque` are you using? Just `append`?

Comment: yes, well appendleft to be more specific (making it easy to print the top results)

Comment: @nodoze Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59061/discussion-between-dano-and-nodoze).